# jQuery - is:visible/hidden not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the string **remove field**  hide and show using one button and based on its current state. Initially, it will be hidden( using hidden HTML attribute) and on click of the button it should appear and click again it should disappear. what am I wrong in the code below?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      
   $(".addlink_manage").click(function () {
            console.log('click working');

            //var toggle_x = $(".remove_field")
            

            if ($(".remove_field").is(":hidden")) {

                $(".remove_field").is(":visible");
            }

            if ($(".remove_field").is(":visible")) {

            $(".remove_field").is(":hidden");
            }

            
        });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
   

</head>
<body>
  <div class="addlink_dynlist"><li><a href="#">Name</a> <a href="#" class="remove_field" hidden> remove field</a></li></div>
 
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class = "addlink_manage"> click me</button>
      
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $(".remove_field").is(":visible"); is not going to hide/show/remove. It is just returns a boolean.

Comment: .hide(), .show() is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `$(".remove_field").is(":visible");` is only returning a boolean value rather than actually hide/show that element.

Just execute a negation to the current prop `hidden`

```
$removeField.prop('hidden', !$removeField.is(":hidden"));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addlink_manage").click(function() {
    console.log('click working');
    var $removeField = $(".remove_field");
    $removeField.prop('hidden', !$removeField.is(":hidden"));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="addlink_dynlist">
    <li><a href="#">Name</a> <a href="#" class="remove_field" hidden> remove field</a></li>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <button class="addlink_manage"> click me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From my comment, `$(".remove_field").is(":visible");` returns a boolean so it is not going to do anything to add and remove an attribute on an element.

Either call `toggle()` no if/else needed

or use `.attr("hidden", true)` and `.removeAttr('hidden');`

or use `.hide()` and `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery().is(":visible/hidden") considers elements visible/hidden for several reasons:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

But, you can hide/show an element more easily if you use [jQuery().toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)